# What is right way to delete model, view, and controller in mvc application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I try to delete model, view, and controller in mvc application ?
But I get errors,

Error   1   Source file 'Controllers\AccountController.cs' could not be found
Error   2   Source file 'Models\AccountViewModels.cs' could not be found
Error   3   Source file 'Models\IdentityModels.cs' could not be found

What is right way to do this?

Comment: Did you delete from `Windows Folder Explorer` or from `Visual Studio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find all references of your controller, model
2. Remove all references first
3. Then delete your controller and model